# OCIEnvCreate failed with return code 1 but error message text was not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, c#-2.0, odp.net

I'm having some trouble with this exception.
I already tried this options that i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901045/ocienvcreate-failed-with-return-code-1-but-error-message-text-was-not-available).

**The causes:
You are using an unsupported version of the Oracle Client (older than 11.2) on Windows 7.
DLLs from a previous installation of Oracle Client have been left on the system, causing a conflict.
The solutions:
Install a supported version of the Oracle Client.
Perform a search for "OCI.DLL" on the local machine. If you find any instances of this file in any location other than your ORACLE_HOME rename or delete it. If in doubt, uninstall the Oracle Client, then perform the search again. Anything that is leftover is the culprit.**

**And I gave permission to all of the Oracle paths. I'm looking for some other solution or help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by editing the .csproj file. In my case, I was using a project to connect to the database and in another application, a console application, I was doing the logic of my program and calling that library. To solve the problem I've checked the section of my .csproj. In the database connection project the "Debug | Any CPU" property was different in comparisson with my console application .csproj. I've replaced it by this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
 <DebugType>full</DebugType>
 <Optimize>false</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```